# how to use username/password as credentials for nodejs grpc?

Tags: node.js, grpc

I'm trying to access the gNMI API on an Arista router. The interface is configured with only username/password (admin/admin) and no certificate.

This CLI command returns the capabilities

```
$ gnmic -a 10.72.47.100:32232 --username admin --password admin --skip-verify capabilities
```

I'm using `@grpc/grpc-js` and `ts-proto` for typescript model generation.
I have not been able to figure out how to make the same API call from node/typescript.

Trying to combine an insecure with a call credentials gives this error
`Error: Cannot compose insecure credentials`

```js
import * as grpc from '@grpc/grpc-js';
import * as gnmi from './proto/github.com/openconfig/gnmi/proto/gnmi/gnmi';


    const meta = new grpc.Metadata();
    meta.add('username', 'admin');
    meta.add('password', 'admin');

    const channelCredentials = grpc.credentials.createInsecure();
    const callCredentials = grpc.credentials.createFromMetadataGenerator( (options, callback) => {
        callback(null, meta);
    });
    const credentials = grpc.credentials.combineChannelCredentials(
        channelCredentials,
        // callCredentials, <-- ** gives error: Error: Cannot compose insecure credentials **
    );

    const client = new gnmi.gNMIClient('10.72.47.100:32232', credentials);
    const req: gnmi.CapabilityRequest = { extension: [] };

    client.capabilities(req,
        (error, response) => {
        if (error) {
            console.error(error);
            process.exit(1);
        }
        console.info(response.gNMIVersion);
    })
```

And passing the meta to the call gives me this error `Error: 14 UNAVAILABLE: Connection dropped`. I assume this is due to missing credentials

```js
    const meta = new grpc.Metadata();
    meta.add('username', 'admin');
    meta.add('password', 'admin');

    const Credentials = grpc.credentials.createInsecure();

    const client = new gnmi.gNMIClient('10.72.47.100:32232', credentials);
    const req: gnmi.CapabilityRequest = { extension: [] };

    client.capabilities(req, meta
        (error, response) => {
        if (error) {
            console.error(error);
            process.exit(1);
        }
        console.info(response.gNMIVersion);
    })
```

```
    code: 14, details: 'Connection dropped',
    metadata: Metadata, stack: 'Error: 14 UNAVAILABLE: Connection dropped
```

Any suggestions as how I can do this ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

gRPC does not allow composing call credentials with insecure channel credentials because call credentials generally contain sensitive information that should only be transmitted over secure connections. The simplest way to handle this is to secure the connection with TLS by using secure credentials on both the client and the server. If that is not an option, you can also pass the metadata directly to each individual request instead of using call credentials.

Comment: I tried that too before asking, but still gives me the same error 
`
client.capabilities(req, meta
        (error, response) => {
`

Comment: I admit, I didn't notice the second error when I first read the question. "Connection dropped" could have a variety of meanings. It's probably not a credentials issue because that would generally result in an authentication error, not a connection error.

Comment: I'm not familiar with gRPC, so this might be a silly question. But is there such thing as different version or setting of gRPC which can cause the 'transport' or Arista API to not be compatible with the 'grpc/grpc-js', and that is what might cause the dropped connection. I

Comment: No, it's not that. There's just one gRPC protocol. The one thing I can think to check is whether the server is actually serving in plaintext, and not TLS, because the client is trying to connect in plaintext.